# Finding grouped items with a full set of attributes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                        'B': ['AF', 'PLAT', 'AF', 'PLAT', 'ROOT'],
                        'C': [.0015, .0018, .0021, .0011, .0008] })

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
      A        B       C
0     1       AF  0.0015
1     1     PLAT  0.0018
2     2       AF  0.0021
3     2     PLAT  0.0011
4     2     ROOT  0.0008
```

and I would like to get a list of all `A`s that have at least 1 each of 'AF', 'PLAT' and 'ROOT' in `B`. By that criteria, only `A` == 2 would be returned, as `A` == 1 doesn't contain 'ROOT'.

This works:

```
In [128]: gbdict = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count().to_dict()['C']

In [129]: gbdict
Out[129]: 
{(1L, 'AF'): 1,
 (1L, 'PLAT'): 1,
 (2L, 'AF'): 1,
 (2L, 'PLAT'): 1,
 (2L, 'ROOT'): 1}

In [130]: features = dict()
         ...: for k in gbdict:
         ...:     features.setdefault(k[0], []).append(k[1])

In [131]: features
Out[131]: {1L: ['PLAT', 'AF'], 2L: ['AF', 'PLAT', 'ROOT']}

In [132]: alist = [k for k, v in features.items() if ('AF' in v and 'PLAT' in v and 'ROOT' in v)]

In [133]: alist
Out[133]: [2L]
```

but there's got to be something more Pandas-centric

Comment: I think people expect you to post the code you played around with, to see if it shows research and effort...

Comment: `for k in gbdict`   insted this try `for k in gbdict.head() :`

Comment: There you go, two upvotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take advantage of the DataFrameGroupBy.filter method, which returns groups whose contents match a given filtering condition:

```
# Define the required groups
req = set(['AF','PLAT','ROOT'])
# Group and filter results
f = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g:req.issubset(set(g.B)))

#   A     B       C
#2  2    AF  0.0021
#3  2  PLAT  0.0011
#4  2  ROOT  0.0008
```

This uses the set comparison .issubset method to figure out if the B entries of each group contain the required values. You can turn this into a one-liner, `df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g:set(['AF','PLAT','ROOT']).issubset(set(g.B)))`, but personally I find explicitly calling out the required values a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, solve the problem for a given value of `A`:

```
df1 = df[df['A'] == 1]
[b in df1['B'].tolist() for b in ['AF', 'PLAT', 'ROOT']]
```

Returns:

```
[True, True, False]  # 'ROOT' is not in column B
```

You can then use `all` to get your answer.

**Second**, `groupby` and `apply` the above as a function to get an answer for each value of `A`:

```
labels = ['AF', 'PLAT', 'ROOT']
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda d: all([b in d['B'].tolist() for b in labels]))
```

Result:

```
A
1    False
2     True
```